# Typehints for ndb Google Cloud Datastore in PyCharm are missing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, google-cloud-datastore, type-hinting

There are no type hints for instance objects of the `ndb` Model class.

For example `some_datetime` does not show any type hints. Type hints work in other places. 
Do I need to install something specifically for type hints to work with the `ndb` library?

```
from google.cloud import ndb

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    some_datetime = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

    def f(self):
        self.some_datetime # PyCharm does not give type hints for datetime obj
                           # I expect hints like .timestamp, .tzinfo, etc
```

Link to [ndb library](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reproduce your issue and I've been looking for this but I haven't managed to find anything neither in Google's nor PyCharm's documentation.

Regardless, I believe this issue has more to do with PyCharm so you should consider submitting a request in their [support page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).